# parse image threw AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I got requirement to pass image into web service. Im using AFNetworking. My code so far is given below.

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imgA.image, 0.5); 
params = @{@"category":self.displayDept.text,
           @"location": locationAdress.text,
           @"topic":self.topic.text,
           @"image":imageData,
           @"email":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",useEmail]
           };



AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager POST:@"webservice....."

   parameters:params  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
       [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"imageData"];

   } success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
```

Could anyone tell what is wrong with this code? Thanks

Comment: You are adding image twice ?? One in parameters and also in multipart ? and both time use different keys ?

Comment: which one will work here ? parameter or multipart ? can u suggest a way for that ?  @Wolverine

Comment: Multipart will work. Remove from paramter.

Comment: when i remove the parameter, shows an error "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set" @Wolverine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting image from pickercontroller and upload image to server.

```
UIImage *img = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    [manager POST:@"<json link>" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:imgData name:@"image"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Hope this solved your problem.